# Accessing Username and Password in django request header returns None

Tags: python, django, basic-authentication

I'm creating a view which is expected to be accessed by a bot passing a username and password in the header. (It's a google feed bot to be specific). However, I can never seem to access the username and password to authenticate the bot's credentials. `request.GET.get('username')` and `request.GET.get('password')` both return `None` since both `request.GET` and `request.POST` return empty QueryDicts. I am using Postman with basic authentication to test my requests. 
Here is my code from `views.py`:

```
def authenticate_bot(request):
    username = request.GET.get('username')
    password = request.GET.get('password')
    feed_bot = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if feed_bot is not None:
        # Confirmed as user credentials.
        login(request, feed_bot)
```

How do I retrieve the username and password from my basic authentication header?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thank you [nthall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/354176/nthall) for pointing me in the right direction - finding the `request.META` dictionary was key.

Since I couldn't find much in the way of resources which explained the process, I'll post the entire Django process for retrieving and authenticating data from the Authorization header here.

```
import base64
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

def header_auth_view(request):
    auth_header = request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']
    encoded_credentials = auth_header.split(' ')[1]  # Removes "Basic " to isolate credentials
    decoded_credentials = base64.b64decode(encoded_credentials).decode("utf-8").split(':')
    username = decoded_credentials[0]
    password = decoded_credentials[1]
    feed_bot = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    # if the credentials are correct, then the feed_bot is not None, but is a User object.
```

Django capitalizes and affixes the 'HTTP_' prefix to any header passed in the request, and as nthall correctly pointed out, it can be accessed via `request.META`.

I isolate the base64 encoded information, which is in the format `'Basic username:password'` by splitting the header over the space so it's just `'username:password'`. Then I decode using base64 and then decode the result to convert the byte-like string to a utf-8 string. Then it's just a matter of isolating the username and password. Then go through the process of authentication.

Comment: Thank you so much for this freakin awesome answer.

Answer (score 2):

Neither `request.GET` nor `request.POST` refers to request headers. The data you're looking for is most likely available in the dictionary at `request.META` -- more details on that in the [HttpRequest docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META). Not sure about the details of your setup but it sounds like you'd be looking for `request.META['username']` and `request.META['password']`