# How do you get the auth parameters from a POST request?

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I am sending a POST request to myself:

`requests.post("http://localhost:8000/api/", json=data, auth=('myuser', 'mypwd'))`

I am using Django to receive the POST request. I want to authenticate that the username and password matches what I have.

```
def myAPI(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':

          # obtain username and password here
```

How can I get the username and password in plain text? I've tried `request.body.decode()`, `request.POST.items()`, `request.META` -- just can't find it! I could send the credentials over in `data` and it would be easy. Alternatively, I can use an API key instead of both username and password, but I wouldn't know how to access that either.

Comment: It _should be_ in `request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']`

Comment: When I do `print('Auth:', request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])` it prints something like `Auth: Basic bX85js03jg9sl` (random chars)

Comment: Aha -- it was encoded in base64. Found on another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016684/accessing-username-and-password-in-django-request-header-returns-none).

Comment: It is not random. It is your username and password, base64 encoded.

Comment: Why is it base64 encoded when all other information is not?

Comment: There is a question for that, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661384/why-base64-in-basic-authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
req_header = request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']
credentials = auth_header.split(' ')[1]
base64_decoded_credentials = base64.b64decode(encoded_credentials)
decoded_utf_credentials = base64_decoded_credetials.decode("utf-8").split(':')
username = decoded_utf_credentials[0]
password = decoded_utf_credentials[1]
```